# Classical Translation for "aura, vibrations, feeling"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, classical-latin, vocabulary, idiom

I have struggled in finding an adequate translation for the above mentioned words, that designate the subtle ambiance that something is thought to emit or convey. Like *"she gives me negative vibes"*. The closest thing appears to be "aer" in the sense in which we use *"an air of ..."* to mean a feeling, aura of. But I am not exactly sure it would be classical since the dictionaries seem to register only proper, unfigurative use of it. Now I suppose that seeking a litteral translation might be the problem here but I wonder whether there is something akin to what I mentioned
In Vatican documents I have actually encountered *"atmosphaera"* and *"conditio"*. But that seems to me to rather correspond to atmosphere in the sense of ambiance as in *"the atmosphere was mournful"*  as in German *"Stimmung"* not the intuitve almost unnoticeable feeling transferred. "A relish of antiquity", "a touch of sanctity", *"it vibes of xyz"*.

Comment: the figurative use of *aer* might not be classical, but of *odor* (small) certainly is. Lewis and Short [reads](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus:text:1999.04.0059:entry=odor) (II): "a scent, inkling, hint, presentiment, suggestion"